# Android, I need to open my folder from intent type to get content?

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to select some videos to submit to server. I am saving recorded videos to my folder. I have tried all the ways. Guys, I need to open my folder from action get content type. But always opens recent screen and this screen is not refreshing. I am moving submitted videos to other folder.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setType("video/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, KEY_PICK_VIDEO);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
public void openFolder() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
+ "/myFolder/");
  intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, KEY_PICK_VIDEO));
}
```

Comment: I tried this code one more for you. Sorry, this code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

`Intent pickVideo = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
pickVideo.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
pickVideo.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivityForResult(pickVideo, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);`

declare this on top of the activity:

`private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;`

[when clicking this screen open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9fwU.jpg)

[after you can select multiple images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFHcG.jpg)

Comment: ACTION_PICK not supported multiple allow and I can't see folders.

Comment: ACTION_PICK supported multiple allow and this code working for me. can you tell me your log cat error?

Comment: No error. Working but i can't select multiple and opening galery tab and i see again recent.

Comment: Ok. That's work fine my phone. I'm sorry and thank you but not working my tablet. Api level 25 not supported multiple selection. My company using this tablet. This code is very nice but I can't integrate my code.